# How to find number of authors with no book published

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have a database with 2 tables : author and book.

```
mysql>
mysql> CREATE TABLE author
    -> (
    ->     a_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # author ID
    ->     name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, # author name
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (a_id),
    ->     UNIQUE (name)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE book
    -> (
    ->     a_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, # author ID
    ->     p_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, # book ID
    ->     title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, # title of book
    ->     state VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, # state where purchased
    ->     price INT UNSIGNED, # purchase price (dollars)
    ->     INDEX (a_id),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

How to find the number of authors who have not published a single book till now?

Answer (score 2):

Use this select for counting the authors with no books published:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
   FROM author AS a
     LEFT JOIN book AS b ON a.a_id = b.a_id
   WHERE b.p_id IS NULL
```

Use

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.name
```

for getting the list of authors with no books published.

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework? You should really tell us what you have tried? That said, this is an easy one:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM author a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM book b WHERE b.a_id = a.a_id)
```

Comment: @M.Hemant what? I was providing the answer, but also merely pointing out that if this is homework getting the question answered on StackOverflow is not a good way to learn

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub query and count to get the number of unique authors from book table and use `NOT IN` with author table to get the authors who haven't written a book

```
SELECT COUNT(a.a_id) as author_count
FROM   author as a 
WHERE  a.a_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT b.a_id FROM book as b)
```